# How can I fix may https POST request?

Tags: javascript, class, https, httprequest

I have a HTTP client class, what has a `post()` method. If I try to send data to the server with this method I get nothing back.

I tried to send data with Postman, that's working fine. So I think here is something problem, but I have no idea what's wrong.

Here is `HttpClient`'s code:

```
export class HttpClient {
 constructor() {
    this.xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
     this.xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
         switch (this.xhr.readyState) {
            case 0:

                 break;
             case 1:

                break;
             case 2:

                 break;
             case 3:

                 break;
             default:

         }
    };
     this.xhr.onload = () => {
         return this.xhr.response;
     };     }

     post(url, async, data) {
         return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
                 this.xhr.open("POST", url, async);
                 this.xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "applicatoin/json");
                this.xhr.send(data);
                resolve(this.xhr.response);
             },
                reason => {
              //DO SOMETHING
             }
         );
     }
```

And here is the code where I try to use this HttpClient:

```
addButton() {
   if (this.items.length < 9) {
         const task = {
           "name" : document.getElementById("Myinput").value,
           "status" : false
       };
        this.httpClient
        .post("http://todoapp.test/api/create", true, task)
          .then(resolve => {
       //DO SOMETHING
          })
         .catch(error => console.log(error));
     }
}
```

Why the resolve doesn't have value in the than method in POST request?

Comment: Typo in `"applicatoin/json"`.

Comment: Thank you! I fiexed but it still not working well.

Comment: Have you checked your developer tools' console? Are there any errors? Have you checked the Network tab in your developer tools? Is the request send at all? Is the response what you expect it to be?